# Querying a database and insert resulting into a table in a seperate database in Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Hi I have two database connections in Oracle SQL developer. I am trying to query results out of one database and insert them into another. If one database is named Issue and the other one named Hub. The table I want the results to go in is in the DB Hub. So in a worksheet in the hub database would I do something like this?

```
INSERT INTO RESULTS
SELECT ...
FROM ISSUE.TABLE1 ISSUE1,
ISSUE.TABLE2 ISSUE2,
WHERE ...
```

However when I do this I get this error:

```
 SQL Error: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
 00942. 00000 -  "table or view does not exist"
```

I am connecting to the database Issue incorrectly?

Thanks,

Comment: Have a look at database links

Comment: Two points.  For insert queries you don't need aliases.  Next, your prose says issues but code sample says issue.

Comment: thanks it worked out, database links is what i was missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably you have problems with your privileges.

Try this:

login as user ISSUE and execute this statement:

```
GRANT SELECT ON TABLE1 TO HUB;
GRANT SELECT ON TABLE2 TO HUB;
```

login again as HUB and try again your select statement.

I'm not at my desk, therefore I can't test it on my own.

If your database users are on different Oracle instances, then you need a database link from HUB to ISSUE.

Answer (score 0):

This came directly out of the manual; 
    INSERT INTO db1.table1(col1) SELECT col2 FROM db2.table2;

Did you try reading the manual about cross database inserts?

Comment: Shouldn't there be a DB link created first?

Comment: By virtue of being able to execute the command I would assume a link is already established to the database you're inserting into - the SELECT from db2 would be the oracle engine establishing a secondary connection? My guess (I'm mainly an Informix dude), would be the user must have permissions on both DBs and if they are on separate servers, they would need to be trusted by each other.